# Buck–boost converter on a lithium battery with a variable DC output

Tags: batteries, dc-dc-converter, buck-boost

I have a battery with a DC port that is rated 9-12V 10A. I don't really know what that means. My guess is that the voltage of the DC port can go from 12V to 9V when the battery capacity is low.

I need to connect some equipment requiring a constant 12V, otherwise they shutdown. They draw ~5A (so 60W) total.

Can I connect a buck-boost converter to the battery on the DC port to ensure the voltage is stabilised to 12V even if the battery voltage of the DC port goes down to 9V?

I saw some buck-boost converters with an input of 8-40V and output of a stabilised 12V 10A max and efficiency of 90-93%.

If I am right and if the DC port goes down to 9V, the equipment + booster would draw (12V * 5A) / (9V * 90%) = 7.4A (which is still under the limit of 10A for the battery.)

Is it possible to connect a boost converter to a lithium battery to force an output of a stabilised 12V even if it depletes the battery faster?

[Link to the battery.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08G1QWH97)

Comment: By "5Ah", do you mean that your 12V equipment draws 5A?

Comment: Yes sorry... I will update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible and very common.  Your math appears to be correct.